# Android Custom dialog get inside View in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I need to get the access to TextView inside dialog to change its properties.  My code looks like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_execute, null);

    builder.setMessage("Execute").setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("Execute", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    filename = view.findViewById(R.id.filename);
                    [...]
```

When i run this i get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dialogXfilename"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="notepad.exe"/>

[...]

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried changing the layout type but the app still crashes when the code is executed

Comment: Sorry I can't see any cast to a TextView in your code snippet. And maybe you can at least post the complete onCreateDialog() ? Plus the layout file

Comment: There should be a line like `final TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.layout.name_of_textview);` to get your TextView which you can edit.

Comment: @Nordii findViewById needs R.id not R.layout. the filename is a TextView and it is declared above the shown code

Comment: That is correct. Thanks for catching that. If the problem is still there, can we see your code?

Comment: Can you post the xml for dialog_execute? Difficult to determine what the problem is without seeing the layout.

Comment: @Bradford2000 xml aded

Answer (score 0):

I just realised thet the

```
android:id="@+id/dialogXfilename"
```

was in the layout not the text view, my bad